# Systemd - running custom VM shutdown script before the standard libvirt-guests.service

Tags: linux, debian, virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization, systemd

On a KVM host I have a few VMs with legacy OSes that do not listen to ACPI shutdown event. As it happens on Debian 9.5 host, on shutdown the `libvirt-guests.service` waits for 5 minutes for each such VM and then destroys it.

In order to avoid that and shut them down cleanly, I have created custom VM shutdown service, with a script that uses special methods to shut them down:

```
% cat /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/vm_stop.service 

[Unit]
Description=vm_shutdown
Before=libvirt-guests.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/vm_shutdown_all.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

However, on shutdown the service appears to run **after** `libvirt-guests.service` in spite of the `Before=` settings in above service.

Now, I have tested that the custom service actually does run on shutdown - it `touch`es a test file where I can verify it.

The problem: how do I ensure that it runs before `libvirt-guests.service`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Before=` statement relates to the start up of the service. From `man systemd.unit`.

> If a unit foo.service contains a setting Before=bar.service and both units are being started, bar.service's start-up is delayed until foo.service has finished starting up.
>   ...
>   Note that when two units with an ordering dependency between them are shut down, the inverse of the start-up order is applied. i.e. if a unit is configured with After= on another unit, the former is stopped before the latter if both are shut down.

So you want to configure your service with `After=libvirt-guests.service` as the service then is started after `libvirt-guests.service` is started and your service is stopped before `libvirt-guests.service` is stopped.